# Copying classes to another classes with the exact same properties

Tags: c#, reflection, recursion, tree

I need to copy all the properties from one class to another. I know how to copy properties if they were just a single object but not if it contains a list of itself.
for example,

```
    public class A
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<A> Ass { get; set; }
}
public class B
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<B> Bss { get; set; }
}
```

and what I have does not work if there is a collection of itself inside

```
if (source != null && destination != null)
        {
            Type sourceType = source.GetType();
            Type destinationType = destination.GetType();
            foreach (PropertyInfo sourceProperty in sourceType.GetProperties())
            {
                PropertyInfo destinationProperty = destinationType.GetProperty(sourceProperty.Name);
                if (destinationProperty != null && sourceProperty.CanRead && destinationProperty.CanWrite)
                {
                    destinationProperty.SetValue(destination, sourceProperty.GetValue(source, null), null);
                }
            }
        }
```

does anyone know a way to copy everything from one class to another even if there is a List of the same class inside itself?  Im thinking something recursive but not sure how to approach.

Comment: If you use the same property name for `Ass` and `Bss`, you can serialize and then deserialize back.(for ex using Json.Net)

Comment: Have your https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper for doing the bulk of the work?

Comment: @KenBrittain autoMapper isnt copying the self referencing List. I am only getting the base properties and nothing pass the first level of the list

Comment: @L.B Okay the serialization worked, after i found that was a circular error in my data. thanks!